# How in python 3.6 to get data array from hdf5 file if dtype is "<u4"?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I want to get dataset with format {N, 16, 512, 128} as 4D numpy array from hdf5 file.
N is a number of 3D arrays with {16, 512, 128} format.
I try to do this:

```
import os
import sys
import h5py as h5
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import re

file_name = sys.argv[1]
path = sys.argv[2]

f = h5.File(file_name, 'r')
data = f[path]
print(data.shape) #{27270, 16, 512, 128}
print(data.dtype) #"<u4"

data = np.array(data, dtype=np.uint32)
print(data.shape)
```

Unfortunately, after `data = np.array(data, dtype=np.uint32)` command it seems that code crashed because nothing happened after.

I need to retrieve this dataset as a numpy array or maybe somthng similiar for further calculations. 
If you have any suggestion, let me know.

Comment: What does `data[:]` produce?  `h5py` also suggests using its own `astype`: `with dset.astype(...):out = dset[:]`

Comment: @hpaulj, can you explain your question a bit more?
what do you mean when asked what ```data[:]``` produce?
what happened when I print ```data[:]```? after or before what?
I did ```prind(data)``` and the result was ```<HDF5 dataset: shape (27270, 16, 512, 128), type "<u4">```

Comment: `data` is an `h5py` dataset object.  `data[:]` is a numpy array (via the preferred, but not only, syntax).

Comment: @hpaulj, ok I got it. the same, I am not sure what is wrong, but nothing happend the window with command line is without changing

Comment: You might not need an array. `data = f[path]` is a h5py dataset object that behaves like an array. If you really need an array, use `data_arr = f[path][:]` -- it returns an array. There is not a good reason to use `np.array()`. The difference: Arrays have to fit in memory. Objects do not have the same memory requirement.

Comment: @kcw78, so if I have an array with the 4D shape, I should use ```data_arr = f[path][:,:,:,:]```, shouldn't I? and one more question - if in further I want to add anoter static array with 3D {16, 512, 128} format for each i in range from 0 to N for data_arr with 4D format {N, 16, 512, 128}, it is possible to do that without converting it into numpy array?

Comment: Good question. I'm pretty sure `data_arr = f[path][:]` will work for any number of dimensions. (FYI, I add `_arr` to my array variables vs `_ds` for dataset variables). What are you doing that requires an array?

Comment: Not sure about your second question...don't think I've done that. However, you can create `data_ds = f[path]` as the object that references the entire dataset (27270, 16, 512, 128). Then you can extract an array by slicing the dataset `slice_arr = data_ds[i,:,:,:]` then reshape to [16, 512, 128].

Comment: @kcw78, try to implement some boolean operation with 3D static array (boolean or) for getting some kind of mask

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems writing/fetching `<u4` and `np.uint32`:

```
In [14]: import h5py                                                                                   
In [15]: f=h5py.File('u4.h5','w')                                                                      
In [16]: ds = f.create_dataset('data', dtype='<u4', shape=(10,))                                       
In [17]: ds                                                                                            
Out[17]: <HDF5 dataset "data": shape (10,), type "<u4">
In [18]: ds[:]                                                                                         
Out[18]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint32)
In [19]: ds[:] = np.arange(-5,5)                                                                       
In [20]: ds                                                                                            
Out[20]: <HDF5 dataset "data": shape (10,), type "<u4">
In [21]: ds[:]                                                                                         
Out[21]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=uint32)
In [22]: np.array(ds, dtype='uint32')                                                                  
Out[22]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=uint32)
In [23]: f.close()
```

You could be hitting a memory limit.  I get a memory error when trying to create an array of that size:

```
In [24]: np.zeros((27270, 16, 512, 128),np.uint32);                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-2cfe704044b6> in <module>
----> 1 np.zeros((27270, 16, 512, 128),np.uint32);

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 107. GiB for an array with shape (27270, 16, 512, 128) and data type uint32
```

You might still be able to load a slice of `data`, e.g. `data[0:100]`.

Comment: with such dataset sure, but if you have the same as I mentioned in post, and you will try to read it from hdf5 file, I think, you will have the same situation.
When you try to work with a small dataset it doesn't make any sense, because it is not a real case

Comment: like a chunking? I will try, it seems more rational way in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you don't even need to reshape.
Here's an example of accessing a dataset then slicing to get the array.
I think it's exactly what you want.

**Edit 30-April-2020**
The OP was in regards to uint32. My initial answer used an array of floats. It demonstrated the desired behavior. For completeness, I made a slight modification to create the dataset from an uint32 integer array.
Note: I used `a0=100`. The HDF5 file it creates is 840 MB for floats and 416 MB for uint32. Multiply that by 273 for `a0=27270`. I don't have nearly enough RAM to create that in one shot. The code below shows the process.

(Note: The dataset was created with `maxshape=None` for axis=0 to allow for expansion. If you are interested in testing larger datasets, you can modify this example by adding a loop to create more data and add to the end of the dataset.)

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

a0 = 27270
a0 = 100
a1= 16
a2 = 512
a3 = 128

f_arr = np.random.rand(a0*a1*a2*a3).reshape(a0, a1, a2, a3)
i_arr = np.random.randint(0,254, (a0, a1, a2, a3), dtype=np.uint32 )

with h5py.File('SO_61508870.h5', mode='w') as h5w:
     h5f.create_dataset('array1', data=i_arr, maxshape=(None, a1, a2, a3) )

with h5py.File('SO_61508870.h5', mode='r') as h5r:
     data_ds = h5r['array1']
     print ('dataset shape:', data_ds.shape)
     for i in range(5):
         sliced_arr = data_ds[i,:,:,:]
         print ('array shape:', sliced_arr.shape)
```

Comment: LOL, no, this is pretty basic h5py stuff. I never create an array unless I absolutely, positively need one for a downstream operation (usually a NumPy function that requires an array as input).